# Express app.get('*') does not apply to '/'

Tags: express

I have a simple express server file.

I am trying to get any code within my app.get('*') block to execute. However, when I put in a console.log it does NOT show up for my root. It works on my other routes, but NEVER on '/' route. For reference I am developing locally so it's not working on http://localhost:8080/

```
const app = express();

const port = process.env.PORT ? process.env.PORT : 8181;
const dist = path.join(__dirname, 'dist');

app.get('*', (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('Why wont you show on /')
});
app.use(express.static(dist));

//These two routes work...
app.get('/info', getInfo);
app.get('/infoDetail', getID);

app.listen(port, (error) => {
    if (error) {
    console.log(error); // eslint-disable-line no-console
}
  console.info('Express is listening on port %s.', port); // eslint-disable-line no-console
});
```

The dist folder has compiled css, js and index.html

Comment: Does it work if you use `app.all('*', (req, res, next) => {`?

Answer (score 1):

I just created a simple test express application:

```
const express = require("express");

let app = express();

app.get('*', (req, res, next) => {
  res.json({ hi: 'there' });
});

app.listen(3000);
```

When I run this example, and hit the / url, I do indeed get the desired JSON response.

Are you sure your example is the exact code you're running?

Comment: Ah, ok this jostled my memory. I am using webpack proxy devServer, so when I go to 8080 it doesn't hit app. I have to be on 8181  `devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    proxy: {
      '/api*': 'http://localhost:8181'
    }
  }`